# Wirtinger's theorem fails to hold in the real case

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, calibrated-geometry

We have a complex manifold $M$ equiped with a hermitian metric, then for a complex submanifold $S \subset W$, the Wirtinger's theorem tells us that the volume form on $S$ is the restriction of a global form on $M$.

The textbook then made the remark that this is not true in the real case. Does anyone have an explicit example to explain that?

Comment: The length of a curve $(x(t), y(t))$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric is given by $\int \sqrt{x(t)^2+y(t)^2} dt$. The form $\sqrt{x(t)^2+y(t)^2} dt$ is not the pullback of $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @eggplant sorry I still did not see why this is not a pullback of a 1 form...?

Comment: You give us the $1$-form on $\Bbb R^2$. As an abstract hint, what happens to the arclength when you reverse orientation on the curve?

Answer (score 0):

Explicit example: Let $M = \mathbb R^2$. Let $\alpha$ be any one form on $\mathbb R^2$. Write
$$\alpha = Adx + Bdy,$$
where $A, B$ are smooth functions. Consider the vector fields $X(x, y) = (B, -A)$ and let $\gamma(t)$ be any intgral curve of $X$. Then
$$\gamma^*\alpha = 0$$
and thus $\alpha$ do not restrict to the volume form on $\gamma$.